# Bootstrap- My bootstrap menu is not switching to collapsed menu once the screen size is reduced?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body id="<?php echo ($itemid ? 'itemid-' . $itemid : ''); ?>">
  <div id="wrapper" class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Begin Navbar-->
    <?php if ($this->countModules('position-9')): ?>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2" <div>
              <img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/206d2l4.png" style="width:104px;height:110px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-9" style="none" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--End navbar-->
      </div>
```

the menu just does'nt gets collapsed once the screen size is reduced. the menu items just goes underneath each other rather than going to collasped menu.

Answer (score 1):

your html is broken

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2" 
        <div>
```

you need to close the div first

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have closed but the issue is the same :(

Comment: sorry to come back at this so late but after you close the other <div> needs to be removed as well. make sure all your tags are correct